# Can you update isolated components of MinGW?

Tags: gdb, mingw, updates, mingw-w64

After installing MinGW-w64 on **Windows 10**, can you update single programs, like GDB alone (without updating the whole MingGW-w64 version)?

If so, how do you do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of those tools have dependencies (in the form of .dll files) and those dependencies have dependencies, etc...

So just replacing the .exe file is usually not the solution (unless it's a staticaly build .exe with no .dll dependencies), and overwriting .dll files that come with the new version mahy break other .exe and .dll files' dependencies.

In conclusion: it's not a good idea unless you keep the single program (like GDB) in a seperate directory.

The https://winlibs.com/ standalone build of MinGW-w64 includes recent versions of tools like GDB, and is always distributed as a whole package to avoid the issues above. Such package is created by building all the components and their dependencies from source.

Comment: thanks. You actually addressed the two solutions I was going to try this weekend. Guess I'm gonna compile the newest version of the GDB and keep it in a separate file, and, then, link the "debbuger" of the IDE (Eclipse, in my case) to the updated file, and keep the "compiler" section linked to the MinGW's 'bin' directory. Do you think it will work that way, or will there also be dependencies not being met?

Comment: Having a compiler suite in one folder and the debugger in another could work, except maybe if there are .dll files the program being debugged depends on that also exist with the same name in in the debugger folder.
If you succeed in compiling a static GDB .exe you can avoid this problem. Another workaround could be to add a custom prefix for the .dll files that GDB depends on (if you also plan to build all the dependancies).